# MySQL Slow Update

Tags: mysql, database, performance

This query takes ~7 seconds (!):

```
UPDATE summary_daily_users
    SET clicks = clicks + 1
    WHERE sum_date = '2018-11-14'
      AND user_id = 120
```

I ran `EXPLAIN` And got this:

[image]

The table has ~300,000 records and `sum_date` is PRIMARY and `user_id` is PRIMARY.

Any recommendations on how to make `UPDATE`work faster?

Comment: I would suggest creating an index on `sum_date` and on `user_id`.

Comment: What's the size of the table, and how many items match your where clause?

Comment: Updated my question with table records count

Comment: Are there other indexes on that table, and how many fields does it have?

Comment: Is the table InnoDB? What is the innodb_buffer_pool_size? What is the innodb_log_filesize?  What MySQL version? These updates, I assume they are frequent, is the sum_date always recent? `SHOW CREATE TABLE summary_daily_users` output also required.  You've listed `sum_date` and `user_id` as primary which can only happen if composite - the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` information will clarify this.

Comment: What is the `PRIMARY KEY` (which it seems to be using)?  Is the table `ENGINE=InnoDB`?  (MyISAM is more likely to take 7 seconds.)

Comment: Here's the `SHOW CREATE` https://pastebin.com/k8m2w9in

Answer (score 0):

What if you add indexes over `sum_date` and `user_id` columns? How many are there rows in the table at all and how many with the values of "2018-11-14" and "120" in these columns?

Comment: The index is already there, and it only fits one row, because it's a primary index.

Comment: please show `SHOW CREATE TABLE summary_daily_users` output in your question. Somehow your explain shows it does not use the PK

Comment: @Alexey - It appears that the `PRIMARY KEY` contains both columns.  Adding two single-column indexes would _not_ help.

Comment: @Rick, if there is really a PK, why isn't it used according to EXPLAIN? I wanted to see SHOW CREATE TABLE, IMHO it would be really helpful to see this in the question if the author wants help.

Comment: @Alexey - Why not using PK?  I'm hoping the `CREATE` will give us a clue.  3 of us have asked for the `CREATE`; let's give him a couple of days, then vote to close.

Comment: I don't mind if the query uses PK, I don't see this in the explain screenshot posted , that's why I asked for show create table

Comment: it is strange that the columns are named differently in your `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and your query in the question. Are you sure you're using the same table? Also someone asked you, how many records are affected with this very `UPDATE`. Please update the question with this info. My bet is that there are many rows affected and the most time consuming part is actually disk write rather than selection. Have you tried the same table and query on a faster drive? E.g. on IO-optimized EC2 instance?